# Как правильно подключать css стили

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

Делаю проект на AngularJS. Есть несколько страниц: index.html, page1.html, page2.html..... Как сделать так, чтобы на всех этих страницах была ссылка на один и тот же файл css? Причём если я захочу поменять название файла, то на всех остальных страницах он тоже измениться.

Comment: сделать один index.html и роутинг

Comment: пример: [Маршрутизация в angularjs](https://metanit.com/web/angular/4.1.php)